# Is LXC can be secure enough for IaaS?

Tags: linux-kernel, cloud, virtualization, lxc

I found on Debian Handbook some isolations limits about LXC.

Those limits are about :

- Memory isolation
- Shared filesystems
- Kernel messages
- Kernel compromission possibilities

For Memory isolation and filesystems, it does not seem to be a problem because it's possible to configure containers to isolate them. But there is a way to secure the Kernel enough to ensure an untrusted user can't compromise the kernel and can't read message kernel ?

If it's possible, is this restrained user access constraining for an IaaS ? Or is not it better to use real virtualization or para-virtualization to offer IaaS solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Linux containers still run under one kernel.  If said kernel is compromised and since that kernel is running in the most privileged hardware mode (ring 0 for x86) it can affect every container running.  With traditional hardware virtualization even if one guest kernel is compromised the hypervisor basically exists in another ring of protection (again x86 terminology) to isolate virtual guests.  Of course it is possible to compromise the hypervisor assuming there is an error in its implementation, but compromising a virtual machine will not directly affect the other guests.

Also a compromised guest could indirectly affect the other guests via the (virtualized) network, i.e. sending malicious messages, but that is analogous to one machine in a network being compromised and doing the same to another machine, without virtualization.  Furthermore, a compromised guest could start to affect the performance of the other machines via micro-architectural elements, e.g. thrashing the cache, or use said micro-architectural elements as a side channel attack to gleam some information about the other virtual machine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So there is a way to secure the LXC containers for the user can't access to the kernel ? I see on this topic : [What are the typical uses cases for LXC versus VM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044225/what-are-the-typical-uses-cases-for-lxc-versus-vm) the LXC containers can be used for IaaS but when i read you, it's seem to be hazardous.

Comment: @MartinDonies A process (in a Linux container) that does not interact with the kernel (via system calls) wouldn't be very useful.  Your best bet would be to limit what capabilities the processes in the container have, how you do that is probably best asked on serverfault.com.  Whether you want to use containers or VMs for IaaS is almost certainly beyond what can be answered in an SO post and is going to get a lot of opinionated answers.  The debate of VMs vs. containers can be a heated one depending on who is asked.